# How to delete columns of dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, allocation

I need help tring to delete columns of 2D array in C++. I've tried the operation by making a copy of the array. It succeeded only from the start to middle or the middle to the end of array. witch algorithm to jump unwanted columns in the array when making copy.

Comment: What is this 2D array made up of? How do you define it?

Comment: You tried to delete something by copying it? Something seems rather off here... In any event, you'll need to provide more details about what you have so far, since there are many ways to define a 2D array (some of which remove the need to explicitly delete columns).

Comment: you're right but the 2D if define using pointers, the solutions will be easy If I use vector

Answer (score 0):

Because of dynamic arrays so the varable of the array is pointer for the first value so you can't get the size or even use sizeof to get the size , but there's no case where you use dynamic arrays witout knowing the size , either fixed or in runtime throw varable

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best way to do this but its' a potential solution

```
int removeColumn(int a){
vector<vector<int>> ret(M);
int i = 0;
for(vector<int> temp : Arr){
        vector<int> tempp(N-1);
        copy(temp.begin(), temp.begin()+a, tempp.begin());
        copy(temp.begin()+a+1,temp.end(),tempp.begin()+a);
        ret[i] = tempp;
        i++;
}
Arr = ret;
return 0;
```

}

Essentially you iterate over each row and use two copy statements to copy from the beginning to an index and from said index + 1 to the end. I'm sure there's a way to do this more elegantly, you could try looking at for_each loops however I doubt you could do it exclusively with copy. Tested it with this code.

https://repl.it/repls/PrettyTerrificOmnipage

Hope this helps